# Data not catching in multi step contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my database I have multi exam papers, for each paper, there are some multiple-choice questions that users have to answer. I use a multi-step form and put every question in one step.

I want to catch user answers but, I am unable to post their answers on the results.php page, please help.

/* Here is the HTML form Code*/

```
<form id="regForm" action="results.php">
<?php
    if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $fetchtarget = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from exam_paper where examPaperID= '$id' ");
        $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchtarget);             
        
        $fetchquestion = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from question where examPaperID= '$id' ORDER BY questionID ");
        while($row1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchquestion)){
            ?>
        <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
        <div class="tab"><?php echo $row1["question_statment"]; ?> <br>
            <section>
                <?php
                    $fetchchoices = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from choice where questionID= '".$row1["questionID"]."' ORDER BY choiceID ");
                    while($row2= mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchchoices)){
                        ?>      
                        <div class="radio-container">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="options" value="<?php echo $row2["choiceStatment"]; ?>" oninput="this.className = ''" required>
                            <label>
                                <?php echo $row2["choiceStatment"]; ?>
                            </label>
                        </div>  
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </section>
            <?php
            if(!empty($_SESSION['position'])){
                if($_SESSION['position']=="Admin"){
                    ?>  
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <li>
                                <label for="Name" class="col col-10"><b>
                                    <a  href="./process/updatequestion.php?id=<?php echo $row1['questionID']; ?>" alt="update the question" ype="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updatequestionModal" >
                                        <font>update</font>
                                    </a>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            </td>
                            
                            <td>
                            <li>
                                <label for="Name" class="col col-10"><b>
                                    <a  href="./process/deletequestion.php?id=<?php echo $row1['questionID']; ?>" alt="delete the question"  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletequestionModal" >
                                        <font color="red">x</font>
                                    </a>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
          <div style="float:right;">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
          </div>
        </div>

    <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <?php
        $sqltotalquestion=  mysqli_query($conn, "select * from exam_paper where examPaperID ='".$_GET['id']."' ");
        $rowtotal= mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqltotalquestion);
        for($i=0; $i<$rowtotal['totalQuestion']; $i++){
            ?>
          <span class="step"></span>
          <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    
    <?php
    if(!empty($_SESSION['position'])){
        if($_SESSION['position']=="Admin"){
            ?>  
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <li>
                            <label for="Name" class="col col-10"><b>
                                <a  href="./process/addQuestion2Choices.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addquestionModal1" >
                                    <font>Add Question with 2 options</font>
                                </a>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                    <li>
                        <label for="Name" class="col col-10"><b>
                            <a  href="./process/addQuestion4Choices.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addquestionModal2" >
                                <font>Add Question with 4 options</font>
                            </a>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    <?php
}
else{
    ?>
    <table>
        <tbody> 
            <th>
                <td><img src="images/notice.png" width="80" height="80"  alt="#"></td>
                <td valign="center" >
                    <h2><font color="Green"></n><br/> Please Select Exam Paper To Start </font></h2>
                </td>
            </th>
        </tbody>
    </table><br />
    <?php
}
?>
</form>
```

/*Here is th JS Code */

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

    function showTab(n) {
      // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

      x[n].style.display = "block";
      //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
      if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
      }
      if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
      }
      //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
      fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
      // This function will figure out which tab to display
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

      // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
      if (n == 1 && !validateForm(currentTab)) return false;
      // Hide the current tab:
      x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
      // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
      currentTab = currentTab + n;
      // if you have reached the end of the form...
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
      }
      // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
      showTab(currentTab);
    }

    function validateForm(currentTab) {
      // This function deals with validation of the form fields
      var x, y, i, valid = true;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
     switch(currentTab){
            case 0:
            if(x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[name="options"]:checked').length < 1)
            {
                 alert("Must check some thing!");
                 return false
            }else{
                    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";

            }
            return true;
            break;
            case 1:
            if(x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[name="options"]:checked').length < 1)
            {
                 alert("Must check some thing!");
                 return false
            }
            else{

                    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";

            }
            return true;
            break;
            case 3:
            if(x[currentTab].querySelectorAll('input[name="options"]:checked').length < 1)
            {
                 alert("Must check some thing!");
                 return false
            }
            else{

                    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
                }
            return true;
            break;
            default:
                for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "") {
              // add an "invalid" class to the field:
              y[i].className += " invalid";
              // and set the current valid status to false:
              valid = false;
            }
          }


     }

      // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:

      // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:

    if (valid) {

        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
      return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
      // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
      var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
      x[n].className += " active";
    }
```

/* Here is results.php */
where I supposed to receive user answers but, It doesn't work.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    // action here
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I missed this the first time. You're missing the `method="post"` from your `<form>` tag. HTML `form` methods default to `get`.

---

I'm not seeing where there is a `<input>` of `Submit`. If that's your next button, that won't work. If you want to test for form submission, you could simply do `if (isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0) {`, but since you probably need to pass the exam_id ($_GET['id']), you might put this right after the opening `<form>` tag:

```
<input type='hidden' name='exam_id' value='<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>' />
```

Then you can have this in result.php

```
if ($_POST['exam_id']) {
```

Comment: if (isset($_POST)) works, but it doesn't pass the values

Comment: check to see what you're getting with `die('<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');`

Comment: I got empty value although I changed radio buttons to `<input type="radio" name="options['. $row2['choiceID']. ']" >` since it's radio buttons within while loop

Comment: just to make sure you're seeing it only when you try to post, does this get you a different result? `if (isset($_POST)) die('<pre>'.print_r($_POST,1).'</pre>');` ?

Comment: No, It's the same result with `if (isset($_POST))`

Comment: Ok, it appears that your form contents depend entirely on $_GET and $_SESSION variables. Are you actually seeing your form and radio buttons?

Comment: Yes, It's. Actually it's depend on $_GET['id'] which is $examID, from that I can access questions.

Comment: DOH! I missed the most obvious cause - please see revised answer.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a lot for your time and help